# android: How android convert definition in xml to activity object?

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm a newbie in android.
Learning about define activity and its attributions in xml file, I want to know how android convert definition of activities in xml to activity object at runtime.
Be curious to find out what hard work android do at background.
I have search with google about this subject, but find nothing.
So why am I here to find answers.
Hoping get response from someone knows about this progress and knowledge.

Best Regards!

Comment: xml that u said is AndroidManifest.xml ?? which xml?

Comment: Any xml that has Activities defined in it.
AndroidManifest.xml yes it has defined main Activity used by Application.
Also the Activity you create by yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please go through these link i hope it will help you [Link1](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-android/) , [Link2](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/213316/xml-based-programming-languages) and [Link3](https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=yTLPU6LnIoPV8geriIHwAg&gws_rd=ssl#q=benefit%20of%20using%20xml%20in%20programming%20language). Third link by Microsoft but for concept , it will help you.

Comment: Thanks for answer.I do know how to parse xml in java

Comment: And I know xml can do some kinds of meta-programming.
Ant it self use xml for programming.
But I also want to know the way android turn activity defined in xml to Activity Object in Android runtime.
Can you give me some resource to that knowledges?